# Why strings.HasPrefix is faster than bytes.HasPrefix?

Tags: string, go, benchmarking, slice

In my code, I have such benchmark:

```
const STR = "abcd"
const PREFIX = "ab"
var STR_B = []byte(STR)
var PREFIX_B = []byte(PREFIX)

func BenchmarkStrHasPrefix(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        strings.HasPrefix(STR, PREFIX)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBytHasPrefix(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bytes.HasPrefix(STR_B, PREFIX_B)
    }
}
```

And I am little bit confused about results:

```
BenchmarkStrHasPrefix-4    300000000    4.67 ns/op
BenchmarkBytHasPrefix-4    200000000    8.05 ns/op
```

Why there is up to 2x difference?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the values of `STR`, `STR_B`, `PREFIX`, `PREFIX_B`?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi updated example )

Comment: note that on my Core2Duo P8600 both benchmarks are performing the same (~20 ns/op), while on i5-2400S they are similar to yours – 5.5 vs 8.5 ns/op

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The main reason is the difference in calling cost of [`bytes.HasPrefix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#HasPrefix) and [`strings.HasPrefix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#HasPrefix). As @tomasz pointed out in his comment, `strings.HashPrefix()` is inlined by default while `bytes.HasPrefix()` is not.

Further reason is the different parameter types: `bytes.HasPrefix()` takes 2 slices (2 slice descriptors). `strings.HasPrefix()` takes 2 strings (2 string headers). Slice descriptors contain a pointer and 2 `int`s: length and capacity, see [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader). String headers contain only a pointer and an `int`: the length, see [`reflect.StringHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StringHeader).

We can prove this if we manually inline the `HasPrefix()` functions in the benchmark functions, so we eliminate the calling costs (zero both). By inlining them, no function call will be made (to them).

`HasPrefix()` implementations:

```
// HasPrefix tests whether the byte slice s begins with prefix.
func HasPrefix(s, prefix []byte) bool {
    return len(s) >= len(prefix) && Equal(s[0:len(prefix)], prefix)
}

// HasPrefix tests whether the string s begins with prefix.
func HasPrefix(s, prefix string) bool {
    return len(s) >= len(prefix) && s[0:len(prefix)] == prefix
}
```

Benchmark functions after inlining them:

```
func BenchmarkStrHasPrefix(b *testing.B) {
    s, prefix := STR, PREFIX
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = len(s) >= len(prefix) && s[0:len(prefix)] == prefix
    }
}

func BenchmarkBytHasPrefix(b *testing.B) {
    s, prefix := STR_B, PREFIX_B
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = len(s) >= len(prefix) && bytes.Equal(s[0:len(prefix)], prefix)
    }
}
```

Running these you get very close results:

```
BenchmarkStrHasPrefix-2 300000000                5.88 ns/op
BenchmarkBytHasPrefix-2 200000000                6.17 ns/op
```

The reason for the small difference in the inlined benchmarks may be that both functions test the presence of the prefix by slicing the `string` and `[]byte` operand. And since `string`s are comparable while byte slices are not, `BenchmarkBytHasPrefix()` requires an additional function call to [`bytes.Equal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Equal) compared to `BenchmarkStrHasPrefix()` (and the extra function call also includes making copies of its parameters: 2 slice headers).

Other things that may slightly contribute to the original different results: arguments used in `BenchmarkStrHasPrefix()` are constants, while parameters used in `BenchmarkBytHasPrefix()` are variables.

You shouldn't worry much about the performance difference, both functions complete in just a few nanoseconds.

Note that the "implementation" of [`bytes.Equal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Equal):

```
func Equal(a, b []byte) bool // ../runtime/asm_$GOARCH.s
```

This may be inlined in some platforms resulting in no additional call costs.

Comment: That not enough of an explanation: If you insert an extra non-inlining function call it's still slower.
Sadly i don't understand what the Equal function in assembly actually does. Can anybody explain?

Comment: @0x434D53 +1, for example, in asm_amd64.s (Line 1312 (runtime·eqstring) and line 1652 (bytes·Equal)) – what the difference in that code?

Comment: @icza thanks, but could you explaing more explicit? =)

Comment: @0x434D53 Made further investigation, see edited answer.

Comment: Passing `-gcflags -m` to `go run` will tell you what gets inlined – and it's only `strings.HasPrefix`, but not `bytes.HasPrefix`. If you disable inlining (`-gcflags -l`) you'll get comparable results (bytes ~10% slower). However, if you disable optimisation all together (`-gcflags -N`) benchmarks will be in favour of comparing bytes. At least on my i5. Saying this, the difference seems to be in compilation magic.

Comment: Thanks, incorporated that into the answer.

Comment: One additional question: I never looked to much into the compiler. The assembly code for string equal and byteslice equals differs mainly in that the byteslice compares the length first. A comment in the source says that the compile ensures the strings passed to eqstring have equal length. Any idea where that happens?

Comment: @0x434D53 I haven't looked into it either, but my guess would be that comparing string constants, it's dealt with at compile time, and comparing non-constant strings, the length comparison is inlined. More details are in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232976/how-does-go-do-string-comparison).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the compiler does some optimizations there.

Comment: I always forget about those flags @tomasz. Thanks for the reminder! :)